# Code sign error following fresh reinstall OS X and Xcode 4.6.3

Tags: ios, xcode, dependencies, code-signing, xcode4.6.3

I have recently completed an erase and fresh install of OS X and applications including Xcode.

I can build & run any app to the iOS Simulator (6.1) without issue. I cannot however build and run to a device, although I could do this prior to the reinstall. Instead I receive the following error under the heading...

> Check Dependencies
>   Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains

I have a valid and current iOS Development account.

I have refreshed my provisioning profiles. Yes I have done some reading, although I am still to understand how these work, so the answer may be locked up in that somehow. (I am new to Xcode and Objective C and have been focussing on the code.)

Hoping someone can help?

Also note that after five years my Time Capsule broke (power supply I suspect) before I could completely restore selected directories, so I am unable to go digging around in my old Library directories for files that might help me now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did a reinstall of your system, so you lost your private key and your certificate that was stored inside your keychain. If you don't have a export from Xcode as backup then you need to request a new key and make new certificates:

It is worth looking in the best practise guide:
[App Distribution Guide: Best practices](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificatesandProvisioningAssets/MaintainingCertificatesandProvisioningAssets.html)

Comment: Thanks Luc, will do some reading and no I do not have a backup, so will take your advice. Thanks again